# Web Service over HTTP with NTLM Authentication

Tags: c#, web-services, asmx

We are trying to create a Web Service which will be consumed over HTTP (not HTTPS), and using NTLM/Windows authentication.  Unfortunately, we can't seem to find that "perfect" combination.  No matter what we try, using Windows authentication always seems to want to force us to use HTTPS; and using HTTP seems to ignore all attempts at Windows authentication.

Here is our app.config thus far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="wsSoap" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00"
            receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false"
            bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
            maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
            messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
            useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
              maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                <security mode="Message">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
                    <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://xyz/xyz/xyzws.asmx" binding="basicHttpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="xyzwsSoap" contract="xyzws.xyzwsSoap"
            name="xyzwsSoap" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

We've also tried creating a new binding using wsHttpBinding instead of basicHttpBinding, but that didn't work either.  Can anyone point us in the right direction?

Comment: I retagged this since you mentioned that you are trying to consume .asmx webservices.

Comment: Were you aware that ASMX is a legacy technology that shouldn't be used for new development? You should use WCF to create your service, as you are already using WCF to consume it.

Comment: No, I was not aware.  We're switching over to WCF now, and it works using the development server with Visual Studio, but can't make it work with IIS.

Answer (score 1):

For Windows Authentication, your security mode needs to be set to `TransportCredentialOnly`:

```
<security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
    <transport clientCredentialType="Windows"/>
</security>
```

Also make sure that your server and client configurations are in sync.

Comment: This didn't seem to work for us.  Could you be more specific by what you mean by "server configuration?"  The ASMX file doesn't come with any kind of configuration file.  (As you can probably tell I don't have much experience with web services, so any help is appreciated)

Comment: asmx? Ah, I thought you were working with [WCF](http://weblogs.asp.net/sreejukg/archive/2010/12/15/create-and-consume-wcf-service-using-visual-studio-2010.aspx) services. The configuration settings you're experimenting with are meant for WCF services and not ASMX services.  See the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11419175/calling-asmx-service-from-c-sharp-app-with-windows-authentication)

Comment: Thanks for the link to both - I'll follow the WCF article more closely to see if there's anything I'm missing.  It works just fine with the Visual Studio development server, but there are numerous problems when I switch over to IIS: 405 errors, more authentication issues, etc.  All are beyond the scope of the original question.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

On your server application (one that hosts service) in Web.config `system.serviceModel/behaviors/serviceBehaviors` you need to create new behavour.

```
<system.serviceModel>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="internalBehaviour">
      <serviceAuthenticationManager authenticationSchemes="Ntlm"/>
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="false" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

then in same `<system.serviceModel>` in `<bindings>` section create

```
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="internal" >
        <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
          <transport clientCredentialType="Ntlm"/>
        </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Then in same `<system.serviceModel>` in `<services>` section (where you are configuring service you are trying to expose)

```
<services>
       <service behaviorConfiguration="internalBehaviour" name="Corp.WebServices.CorePricingService">
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="internal" name="ConveyancingEndpoint" contract="Corp.Core.Interfaces.ICorePricingService" />
  </service>
```

(Change contract obviously)

then if you are running it from `IIS Express` in Visual Studio (or IIS), go to `applicationhost.config`

on Win7:
IISExpress `C:\Users\[username]\Documents\IISExpress\config`
IIS `%WINDIR%\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config`

find `<authentication>` section for your website 
set everything (but `<windowsAuthentication enabled="true">`) to `false` and Comment out `<!--<add value="Negotiate" />-->` (or delete)

```
<authentication>
            <anonymousAuthentication enabled="false" />
            <basicAuthentication enabled="false" />
            <clientCertificateMappingAuthentication enabled="false" />
            <digestAuthentication enabled="false" />
            <iisClientCertificateMappingAuthentication enabled="false">
            </iisClientCertificateMappingAuthentication>
            <windowsAuthentication enabled="true">
                <providers>
                    <!--<add value="Negotiate" />-->
                <add value="NTLM" />
                 </providers>
            </windowsAuthentication>
        </authentication>
```

Then in your client app in Web.config

```
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="ConveyancingEndpoint">
      <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly" >
        <transport clientCredentialType="Ntlm"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="http://localhost:53769/CorePricingService.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ConveyancingEndpoint" contract="ServiceReference2.ICorePricingService" name="ConveyancingEndpoint"> 
  </endpoint>
</client>
```

You might need to [set up windows authentication on your local machine](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/authentication/windowsauthentication).

Hope this saves you some time.